# Writing in a file ? Julia language

Tags: file, julia

Here’s an overview of my file :

```
[2020/06/18 17:19:25] Window closed --> OptionDialog = 'Waiting Dialog - Session restore'  -->  frame = 'DataManager' 
[2020/06/18 17:19:40] Window opened -->  frame = 'DataManager' 
[2020/06/18 17:19:40] MB1  --> Menu item = [Toolbox]  -->  frame = 'DataManager' 
[2020/06/18 17:19:42] MB1  --> Menu item = [2G&R Synthesis toolbox, Toolbox]  --> Popup Menu -->  frame = 'DataManager' 
[2020/06/18 17:19:42] Window opened -->  frame = 'ToolBox' 
[2020/06/18 17:19:42] Window gained focus -->  frame = 'ToolBox'
```

I would like to retrieve only the lines with the substring “Window” just after the dates and then write them in a new text file.
Here's what I have done so far :

```
file = open("Test2.txt") do file
    f = readlines(file)
    for line in f
      if line[23:28]== "Window"
         open("t.txt","w") do file
         write(file,line)
         end
      end
   end
end
```

My problem is that only the last line containing "Window" from the first file is written to the new file.
For exemple here it would be :

```
[2020/06/18 17:19:42] Window gained focus -->  frame = 'ToolBox'
```

How do I make sure that **ALL** the lines containing "Window" are written to the new file?

Thank you in advance for your answers,

Valentine

Comment: Have a look at the function `eachline` which will reduce the amount of code you need by a few lines.

Comment: I was just writing this :). And agreed - this is a preferred way to do it as it does not have to read in the whole file into memory.

Answer (score 5):

First, I think you should replace `write(file, line)` to `println(file, line)`
as otherwise newline will not be printed.

There are several solutions to your problem:

The simplest is to change `"w"` to `"a"` in `open("t.txt","w")`; the problem with it is that if the file exists new lines will get appended to it

Normally you would open the file for writing only once and use something like:

```
open("Test2.txt") do file
    f = readlines(file)
    open("t.txt", "w") do file2
        for line in f
            if line[23:28] == "Window"
                println(file2, line)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Finally you do not need to use `readlines` as it will eat-up a lot of memory for large files, and can process the file line by line like this:

```
open("t.txt","w") do file2
    for line in eachline("Test2.txt")
        if line[23:28] == "Window"
            println(file2, line)
        end
    end
end
```

Also note that the check `line[23:28] == "Window"` is only correct if you know you have only ASCII characters in your file and you are sure that your lines are long enough to have 28 characters (or an error will be thrown in your code if it does not have that many characters). If you were not sure that this is the case better use:

```
startswith(chop(s, head=22, tail=0), "Window")
```